# Why is Get written before Set in classes almost all the time, is there a reason?

Tags: c#

So for a while now as i am self taught i have been writing Set before Get in my classes.

```
public class Foo
{
  public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

I've never had any issues doing this, and, logically to me setting before getting just makes sense when reading it. Even though there is no difference either way.

But almost every code example places get before set:

```
public class Foo
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a reason? Is it just a habit thats past on to people? 
Or is there some readable benefit placing get before set as code gets more complex that i might not yet have come to realise?

Comment: I'm assuming since people are voting to close, the answer is simply there is no reason for why people do it...seems i won't get an answer if it gets closed.

Comment: For me it is easier to read `getset` than reading `setget`. It mean reading loudly. It flows better when get is the first vowel. Maybe that's why they are writing it first because it is easier to say "hey did you add get set  methods? "

Comment: I can understand that. Not sure who voted me down for asking this - guess they must be horrified by set before get :D

Comment: There's very very few times when you want to create a write-only property.  So we usually write get first because 99.9% you need a getter.  Set is second because you omit set for the much more common read-only property. At least that's my guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes down to personal preference as the compiler will implement either way and have the same functionality.

However, if you use the `prop` shortcut in visual studio it will populate in the order of get then set.  You do this by typing prop and then hitting the tab key twice.

You can read more about this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx

Comment: I see, it just seems like 99% personal preference is get before set. I don't think i've ever seen set before get except my own code. Made me think it was wrong on a technical reason. Thanks for explaining :) It also seemed like no one had ever asked lol

Comment: @Sir Typically with a property a getter is more common to be the public method, and is the one you would specify in the interface. Then, when you generate interface implementation, it will place just the get there.